# Preventing URI navigation

Tags: java, web-applications, permissions, uri, vaadin

I am using the java framework Vaadin to create a web application.  There different user levels for this application, and when the user logs in I change the menu depending on their permission level.  The problem I am having is preventing a user from visiting a page they are not suppose to by typing in the URI.  For example if a user logs in to the application and only has permission to view page one he can still access page two by typing the URI to page two in the browsers search bar.

I was looking into preventing URI navigation, but was unsuccessful in finding out how this is done in Vaadin.  So my question is how to prevent URI navigation in Vaadin? If you have a different method of preventing users from accessing pages they are not suppose to please feel free to post that as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the  [Vaadin 7 Navigator](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.navigator.html) to do URI Navigation, you can register as ViewChangeListener: if you return "false" in the beforeViewChange method, you can stop the navigation to the new view (and display an error message if you so wish).

For example,

```
navigator.addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    View newView = event.getNewView();
    String newViewName = event.getViewName();

    return canUserAccessView(newView, newViewName);  
  }

  @Override
  public void afterViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    //NO-OP
  }
});
```

My main project doesn't use Navigator, as it was started before Vaadin 7: we developed a very similar framework, that uses a URIFragmentListener to do the same thing.

Comment: This answer is good I think  and Charles has answered almost all of my questions regarding vaadin correctly. here is my +1

Comment: When I add a ViewChangeListener it seems to interfere with my login page.  I added the the the listener to my UI page and it no longer takes me to the login page

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using a vaadin **Navigator**. It allows to navigate through views. So you have to direct to the login view whenever `init(VaadinRequest request)` is called. Other times when the button click or any other component event to go to a different view you can use Navigator to navigate the relevant view in the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Vaadin, but I read that you can use MVC there. If you are using MVC, you have to specify something like this in your controller.

```
public static Result view_contacts(String currentUser) {
        if (currentUser == "guest") {
            return GO_UNAUTHORIZED;
        }
            //code here
}
```

This is simular how I do it in my Java Play Framework application.